# Java variable not initialized in loops?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm doing a course management system using java, and I want to check if a course if already enrolled.

Here is  my code

```
boolean duplicateCheck;

for (int i=0; i<enrolledCourses.size(); i++) {
    if (enrolledCourses.get(i) == searchResult.get(Integer.parseInt(userInput)-1)) {
        duplicateCheck = true;
        break;
    } else {
        duplicateCheck = false;
}

if (duplicateCheck) {
    System.out.println("You've already enrolled in this course!");
} else {
...
}
```

But in the second if statement it says

```
The local variable duplicateCheck may not have been initialized
```

What's wrong with my code? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: What happens if `enrolledCourses` is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables must be initialized before use！

[Definite Assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html)

Do you think that when statement `if (duplicateCheck)` is executed, `duplicateCheck`  is already assigned?

But you overlooked one point, `enrolledCourses.size()` may be equal to zero, in this case, the for loop will not be entered, and `duplicateCheck`  will not be assigned

Answer (score 0):

If `enrolledCourses.size()` is 0, then the loop body won't be executed. The solution is simple:

```
boolean duplicateCheck = false;

for (int i=0; i<enrolledCourses.size(); i++) {
    if (enrolledCourses.get(i) == searchResult.get(Integer.parseInt(userInput)-1)) {
        duplicateCheck = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

or more elegant solution using streams:

```
boolean duplicateCheck = i<enrolledCourses.stream() 
   .anyMatch(course -> course == searchResult.get(Integer.parseInt(userInput)-1));
```

Comment: The second solution is cool, I'll have a look at streams these days